# How can I convince OS X to open txmt:// URLs in MacVim?

Tags: macos, url, vim, schema, macvim

I guess there's not much else to the question.  OS X 10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, use the [`mvim://`-protocol](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/cdefab4132f2fb07889607f63ec0b8f658a39072/runtime/doc/gui_mac.txt#L533-L551) instead. It should be compatible with the `txmt://`-protocol.

If you are not able to change the links themselves, you could try editing the `Info.plist` for MacVim.

Comment: huzzah, it took a year, but this is it!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether plugin for this «protocol» already exists, but if you want to write your own, you should take a look at BufReadCmd event (and also BufWriteCmd). If you don't want to start from scratch, some such events are defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` (for example, for `ftp://` protocol) file which should come with your vim installation.